# Returning List as Json and viewbag from same controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 applciation. I have a jquery ui dialog. On Ok button of this dialog, I am opening another jquery ui dialogue. In order to populate the newly opened popup, I am using jquery ajax call which returns a collection. I am using this collection to create table rows. Code is here:

```
$("#Prices").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   autoResize: true, buttons: {
      "OK": function () {       
         var PirceCurrencies = $('#PirceCurrencies').val();                      
         jQuery("#hdCurrencyId").val(PirceCurrencies);                           
         jQuery(this).dialog('close');
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Home/GetRecordingRates",
            data: { Id: $("#hdCurrencyId").val() },
            success: function (data) {                           
               $("#results").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
               var messages = data.Result;                       
               $.each(messages, function(k, v) {   
                  var row = $('<tr>');                   
                  row.append($('<td>').html(v.DialPrefix));
                  row.append($('<td>').html(v.Rate)); 
                  $('#results').append(row);                                                                                                  
               });
               jQuery('#RecordingRates').dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });
               $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
               $("#RecordingRates").dialog({ dialogClass: 'transparent' });
               $('#RecordingRates').dialog('open');
            }
         }); 
      }
   },
   open: function () {
      $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').focus();
      $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').addClass('customokbutton');
   }
});
```

and controller action is:

```
public JsonResult GetRecordingRates(int Id)
{
   List<DefaultRateChart> defaultRateCharts = new List<DefaultRateChart>();
   Currency currency = new Currency();

   using (IDefaultRateChartManager defaultRateChartManager = new ManagerFactory().GetDefaultRateChartManager())
   {
      defaultRateCharts = defaultRateChartManager.GetAll().Where(rc => rc.Currency.Id == Id
            && (!rc.NumberPrefix.StartsWith("#") && !rc.NumberPrefix.Equals("Subscription")
            && !rc.NumberPrefix.Equals("Default")) && rc.AccountCredit == "Credit").ToList();
   }

   using (ICurrencyManager currencyManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCurrencyManager())
   {
      currency = currencyManager.GetById(Id);
      ViewBag.currecycode = currency.CurrencyCode;
      ViewBag.countrycode = currency.CountryCode;
   }

   return this.Json( new {
      Result = ( from obj 
                 in defaultRateCharts 
                 select new { 
                    Id = obj.Id, 
                    DialPrefix = obj.NumberPrefix, 
                    Rate = obj.PurchaseRates  
                 }
               )
   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

All this works fine but I need to show some other data on newly opened popup other than the collection which populates/create html table rows. Fort that do I need to make another ajax call to another controller action which will return the data ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you return now in your controller:

```
new {
    Result = ( ... )
}
```

You are returning an object with 1 property named Result. In your javascript code you get that object returned named data and you retrieve the Result property as your list.

What stops you from adding more properties to that list?

```
new {
    result = ( ... ),
    currencyCode = currency.CurrencyCode,
    countryCode = currency.CountryCode
}
```

In javascript you can then use `data.currencyCode` and `data.countryCode`

Answer (score 0):

From Controller Action Method you can Return Dictionary like below.

**Sample Code - C#**

```
var dic = new List<KeyValuePair<short, object>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<Int16, object>(1, SomeObj),
    new KeyValuePair<Int16, object>(2, SomeObj),
    new KeyValuePair<short, object>(3, SomeObj),  
    new KeyValuePair<Int16, object>(4, SomeObj)
};

return Json(dic, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Sample Code - JQuery- Access Dictionary objects**

```
var obj1; //Global Variables
var obj2; //Global Variables
var obj3; //Global Variables
var obj4; //Global Variables

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: true,
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Parameter: Value }),
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    complete: function () { },
    success: function (data) {
        DataSources(data);
    }
});

function DataSources(dataSet) {
    obj1 = dataSet[0].Value; //Access Object 1
    obj2 = dataSet[1].Value; //Access Object 2
    obj3 = dataSet[2].Value; //Access Object 3
    obj4 = dataSet[3].Value; //Access Object 4
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. actually  defaultRateCharts is a list of custom objects which i am using in html, where as currency is another custom object ( not a list) which needs to be used on same popup. Can I return both a collection and a custom object from one controller action ?

Comment: Yes. You must do it in one shot and setting the debugger in your JS code is very useful. In this way you can check the JSON and Enumerate the List/Object will become very easily.

Comment: You mean, I need to add currnecy to my Json object ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow return a Dictionary. convert your collection to string and other object to string and return dictionary<int, string>

Answer (score 0):

return a Dictionary from your controller. 
convert your collection to string and other object to string and return

```
dictionary<int, string>
```

in your javascript sucess function,

```
JSON.parse(data[0].key) will give you your collection
```

This will give you an idea

```
    bool inCart = false;
Cart MyCart = default(Cart);
Dictionary<string, string> Result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Result.Add("inCart", inCart.ToString().ToLower());
Result.Add("cartText", MyCart.CartText());
string ResultString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Result);
return ResultString;
```

Here I am adding two types to a dictionary and returning my serialized dictionary

Comment: How I will populate the dictionary with collection and a custom object ( may be two custom object) at the same time ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow added a sample code to my answer, that may give you an idea.